# in() in Guice's bind()... what does it do?

Tags: java, guice

In Guice's documentation, the chapter about [Untargetted Bindings](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/UntargettedBindings) presents this example:

```
bind(AnotherConcreteClass.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

What does the `in()` do? The doc doesn't mention what it is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the scope I think.  It also accept the Scopes enum - either Singleton or NO_SCOPE.

> A scope is a level of visibility that instances provided by Guice may
>   have. By default, an instance created by the Injector has no scope,
>   meaning it has no state from the framework's perspective -- the
>   Injector creates it, injects it once into the class that required it,
>   and then immediately forgets it. Associating a scope with a particular
>   binding allows the created instance to be "remembered" and possibly
>   used again for other injections.

http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0/javadoc/com/google/inject/Scopes.html#SINGLETON